# Stripping time (in the format hh:mm) from a string in Python 2

Tags: python

I have been trying to strip out all the occurrences of sequences of text that are in the format

```
'%d:%d'
```

(for example, 05:45) from a string. I have tried the following code:

```
def remove_times(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == ':':
            s = s.replace(s[i-2:i]+':'+s[i:i+3], '')
return s
```

This is not a solution to my problem for a few reasons and it doesn't work in the form given above either.

My problem is I don't know how to replace patterns which take the form above. It seems like there would be a neat way of doing this but I can't find it.

For example a sample input would be:

```
'the time is currently: 05:52'
```

And the corresponding output would be:

```
'the time is currently: '
```

So the whole time gets deleted from the input and returned.

Comment: can you show what is `s`, what it is returned, sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `re.sub`.

```
import re
def remove_times(s):
    return re.sub(r'[012]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]', '', s)
```

Result:

```
>>> remove_times('hi my name is 4:30 bob')
'hi my name is  bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `re.sub`

```
import re
>>> a = "this is test 4:32 i am here"
>>> re.sub("\d?\d:\d?\d","",a)
'this is test  i am here'
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove the entire time, not just the colon.

Comment: That removes the ':' but it doesn't remove the whole time from a string, which is what I'm trying to do. In answer to your question above, a sample input would be: 'this time needs to be deleted: 05:52' and the output would be 'this time needs to be deleted: '

I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @jholzer can you please give the sample input and sample output, it easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a perfect spot for some regex :)

```
import re
m_re = re.compile(r'\d+:\d+')
cleaned = m_re.sub('', 'some234:327string1:2here')
print(cleaned)
>>> somestringhere
```

Answer (score 0):

you can us `re.sub`: [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'the time is currently: 05:52'
>>> re.sub(r'\d?\d:\d\d ?',r'',string)
```

- `\d`:  means a digit.
- `\d?`: means could be a digit or nothing.
- `?`: means last character can be space.

then it replace pattern with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the way to do this....

```
import re
str="123:456 this is 05:45 and soon after at 06:10 we will go to platform 9"
re.sub('[ ][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[ ]','',str)
```

Will return

'123:456 this isand soon after atwe will go to platform 9'